# How can I destroy a record in a join table with has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, join, favorite

I am creating an app where a user can favorite a room. I accomplished this with
a has_and_belongs_to_many association. I chose this instead of has_many :through because this requires a third model (which could be Favorite) and it would only be used to create the association.

**How can I add a unfavorite(destroy) action into the view or controller?**

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
def favorite
    room = Room.find(params[:id])
    current_user.rooms << room unless current_user.rooms.exists?(room)
    redirect_to wishlist_path
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
post 'rooms/:id/favorite' => 'rooms#favorite'
```

**show.html.erb (room)**

```
<div>Add to Wishlist</div>
<%= form_tag(controller: "rooms", action: "favorite", method: "post") do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Favorite"%>
<% end %>
```

**wishlist.hmtl.erb**

```
<% current_user.rooms.each do |room| %>
    <%= room.listing_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) is your best friend!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work. Say you have the room to unfavorite for the user and save the room as `@room`. Then you can simply do `current_user.rooms.delete(@room)` and I believe rails will do the rest. This works with `has_many` but I cannot currently test with an `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, it's worth a try!

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference#methods-added-by-has-and-belongs-to-many-collection-delete-object)

Comment: I did this in my controller:   def favorite
    room = Room.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.rooms.exists?(room)
      current_user.rooms.delete(@room)
    else
     @room = current_user.rooms << room
      redirect_to wishlist_path
    end
  end  <--- Unfortunately I am getting an association type missmatch error :/ But thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

> I chose this instead of has_many :through because this requires a
>   third model (which could be Favorite) and it would only be used to
>   create the association.

I would actually go with the opposite, and pick `has_many through`. Then, to remove a room from favorites, you can simply `destroy` the association by doing:

```
...
FavoriteRoom.find_by(
  user_id: current_user.id,
  room_id: params[:room_id]
).destroy
...
```